# Can you configure an ItemReader for a Partitioner in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch, partitioning

I have the following requirement: a CSV input file contains lines where one of the fields is an ID. There can be several lines with the same ID. The lines should be processed *grouped by ID* (meaning, if one line fails validation, then all lines with that same ID should fail to process). The groups of lines can be processed in parallel.

I have an implementation that works fine, but it is reading the CSV input file using my own code in a Partitioner implementation. It would be nicer if I could use an out-of-the-box implementation for that (e.g. FlatFileItemReader) and just configure that just like you would for a Chunk step.

To clarify, my job config is like this:

```
<batch:job id="job">
    <batch:step id="partitionStep">
        <batch:partition step="chunkStep" partitioner="partitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </batch:partition>      
    </batch:step>       
</batch:job>

<batch:step id="chunkStep">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <batch:chunk reader="reader" processor="processor" writer="writer" chunk-completion-policy="completionPolicy">
            .. skip and retry policies omitted for brevity              
        </batch:chunk>              
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="partitioner" class="com.acme.InputFilePartitioner" scope="step">
    <property name="inputFileName" value="src/main/resources/input/example.csv" />
</bean>

<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg value="#{stepExecutionContext['key']}"/>   
</bean>
```

where the Partitioner implementation reads the input file, "manually" parses the lines to get the ID field, groups them by that ID and puts them in Lists, and create ExecutionContexts that each get one of those Lists.

It would be great if I could replace that "manual" code in the Partitioner by a configuration of FlatFileItemReader with an ObjectMapper. (I hope I express myself clearly).

Is it possible ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just load the file into a temp table in a db?  This type of aggregation/validation is much easier using SQL.

Comment: The aggregation/validation part is custom code in any case. My question was intended to ask about a way to use an existing configurable utility like FlatFileItemReader, to read and parse a CSV input file in the first place.. (before any aggregation takes place). Just like you would in a read-process-write Chunk step.

Comment: Yes, it is sorted by the ID field used in the grouping

Comment: In that case, you could create a step that reads the file and divides it into files by id then use the `MultiResourcePartitioner`.  But there is no out of the box partitioner to handle your case.

Comment: In the end I did not use MultiResourcePartitioner because I found it a bit silly to first read and parse the input file, then write to files that then needs to be read and parsed again. However you did point me to my new solution:

first, a chunk step uses FlatFileItemReader to read and parse the input file; its Writer groups the items in Lists, which are set in the step's ExecutionContext.

Comment: then, the next step has a promotionListener to copy the lists to the job's ExecutionContext, and a Partitioner which takes them from there and creates Step ExecutionContexts for each. Then another chunk step with a ListItemReader processes each list separately and in parallel.